# Assigning encounter number using two variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I've tried to Google and read around this problem, but I can't seem to find an adequate solution. I'm hoping someone here can help me. I'm sorry if it's too simple but I would appreciate any advice or help.

I'm working with a longitudinal dataset and I would like to assign an encounter number for each person (ID) who may have had one or more interactions with our laboratory (accesssion). The dataset looks something like this, and I would like to create a new variable (encounter) that numbers each unique encounter for each individual sequentially.

```
ID    accession    encounter
----------------------------------
1     1234         1
1     1234         1
1     1235         2
1     1236         3
1     1236         3
2     1000         1
2     1001         2
2     1001         2
3     1111         1
3     1112         2
4     1001         1
4     1001         1
```

I've tried using first.variable statements such as:

```
data new; set old;
by id accession;
if first.id & first.accession then encounter=1;
else encounter+1;
run;
```

I haven't been successful because it won't retain the same encounter number if both the id and accession number remain the same.

Thank you in advance for helping to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close. At the first of each ID you want to set it to 0, and at the first of each accession you want to increment.

```
data new; set old;
by id accession;
Retain encounter;
if first.id then encounter=0;
If first.accession then encounter+1;

run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works beautifully. I really appreciate your help! Cheers! :)